# I'm trying to join a set object in a method and using async fetch hook for fetching the data on server-side and its showing me an error in Nuxt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to fetch data from API on Server Side using `async fetch()` but now in the method, I'm trying to join a set object, that I'm calling it in the template and it isn't working.
Always giving me an error that `required function is not a function`.
Any idea on how to fix that?

Comment: need more details, can you share error/code snippet?

Comment: @kritiz Hey! Thanks for replying but I found the mistake and answered my question.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem. The thing was that I wasn't using the right way to join a set. I was using

```
setObj.join("; ")
```

and this was working fine on the client-side.

But I think because of the different render engine on the server-side. It wasn't resolving.
Solved it using

```
[...setObj].join("; ")
```

This was a JavaScript mistake rather than Nuxt.

I'm new to this thing. Correct me if I'm wrong somewhere.

Comment: Self-answers are welcome on SO but the question should be answerable, too. Nothing in the OP suggested that you use `setObj` and that it's a set. Yes, if it is, it needs to be converted to an array first.

Comment: @EstusFlask Thanks! I tried to edit the question and answer so that it would make more sense. I'm really new to this thing and thanks for the suggestion.